# How does Deprecated ReplaceWith work for Kotlin in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I wrote this code:

```
@Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("test2"))
fun test1(i: Int) {
    println("old Int = $i")
}

fun test2(i: Int) {
    println("new Int = $i")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    test1(3)
}
```

and for some reason when I press Alt+Enter and click "Replace with `test2`", the method `test1` disappears and doesn't get replaced, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

It does work for classes though:

```
@Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("Test2"))
class Test1
class Test2

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = Test1()
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to tell how it needs to be replaced exactly... While I do not know why it was just completely deleted, I will show you what I mean instead:

If you would use the following instead:

```
@Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("test2(i)"))
```

it will replace your `test1(5)` call to `test2(5)` correctly.

Note also that sometimes you may want to add the package name also if it isn't that clear which replacement should take place, e.g.:

```
@Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("org.example.test2(i)"))
// or just use:
@Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("test2(i)", /* here come the imports */ "org.example.test2"))
```

You can also use static values in the replacement in case that is what you need.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot! The problem was that I didn't pass the parameter. I get it.